# Usage of -ないことになる

Tags: grammar

I have heard and read something that sounds like:

> xxxはできないことになります
>
> It became impossible to do xxx

Is this correct and should the preceding verb be in this form only?
To express the same meaning, could one use 「ように」or other grammatical constructs?

Comment: Some more context might help.

Comment: I am not really looking for a translation. Any answer can set up a context for examples, my main issue is that I do not remember precisely if this is correct and common grammar and how to use it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's correct (aside from tense of the verb) and the verb should be adnominal form (attributive form) since こと is a noun.
ように・・ is also correct and actually more common for that meaning, though it doesn't mean "(if that was the case) that means you wouldn't be able to do it".